# How to solve this Riccati Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve following Differential Equation

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{x^2} - y^2$, $x >0$

I know  this is a Riccati Equation, but I am unable to see the substitution required to convert this into a Linear Differential Equation.

Any hints will be helpful.

Thank You.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html

Comment: @night_crawler *If* your question has been answered, please consider ['accepting'](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) one of the answers, so that this question is marked as resolved.

Comment: @Sal: Yeah, sorry for that I was busy with work so it clearly slipped my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $y_p=c/x$, we find for $c$

$$c^2-c-1=0$$

Substituting $y=y_p+u$ into the original equation, we find the differential equation for $u$

$$ u'+u^2=- \frac{2c u}{x}$$

Now let $v=1/u$ to find

$$ v'=\frac{2cv}{x}+1$$

Which is easily solvable, as the nonlinear term has been eliminated. The homogeneous solution is

$$ v(x)_H=Ax^{2c}$$

A particular solution is

$$ v_P(x)=Bx$$

For which we find $B=\frac{1}{1-2c}$. Our solution for $v$ is

$$ v(x)=\frac{x}{1-2c}+Ax^{2c}$$

Hence, the solution for $y$ is

$$ y(x)=\frac{c}{x}+\left(\frac{x}{1-2c}+Ax^{2c} \right)^{-1} $$

$A$ is your constant of integration, and $c$ has values $ \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{x^2} - y^2$$
Try to find a particular solution like:
$$y_p=\dfrac {C}{x}$$
Then substtute  $y=y_p+u$

Comment: I don't see simplifications. This lead to $$u^2+u'+\frac{\sqrt{5} u}{x}+\frac{u}{x}=0$$

Comment: Then what you have is Bernoulli differential equation  just factorize the u terms @Raffaele .. $$u^2+u'+u(\frac {\sqrt{5}} {x}+\frac {1}{x})=0$$